# Reduce number of template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I would like to store some objects I know at compile-time in a class, and keep them `constexpr`, in order to proceed at compile-time. However, the way I'm storing these values in a `struct` seems unsatisfactory:

```cpp
template <class T1, T1 _x1, class T2, T2 _x2>
struct A
{
   constexpr static T1 x1 = _x1;
   constexpr static T1 x2 = _x2;
}
```

While the code above achieves my goal, it seems unnecessarily complicated to have to provide both type and value explicitly in order to store a `constexpr` value in a templated class.

Is there a better/more elegant way of achieving this? In particular one, where I do not have to deduce the type again first would be desirable.

Comment: I think you can simply give `A` a `constexpr` constructor.

Comment: `_x1` and `_x2` are part of the class template.  You don't need variables to them, you can just use them in the class be using their name like `void cool_func() { std::cout << "_x1: " << _x1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17 you can have the auto template parameters

```
template <auto _x1, auto _x2>
struct A
{
   // Use _x1 and _x2 directly
}
```